# Many sessions AWAITING COMMAND

Tags: sql-server, performance, session

I need some guidance please.
An application is going through migration and the processes seem to be quite cpu intensive. CPU utilisation on the server is very high - in the 90's.

The headblocker session appears to be processing, as the 'Last Batch' column is current and no waiting time reported.

There are however, a number of sessions which are in `AWAITING COMMAND`.

[Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/kill-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says not to kill these sessions:

> Use KILL carefully, especially when critical processes are running.
> You can't kill your own process. You also shouldn't kill the following
> processes: AWAITING COMMAND

I would appreciate some suggestions on how to proceed please.

Thank you.

Comment: What value do you see under `open_tran_count` for those sessions?

Comment: To clarify, cpu on which server is high? And what exactly do you mean by that - is there cpu queueing or are there just processes doing work? 'AWAITING COMMAND' means the DB session is waiting to be told what to do - the application server hasn’t given it a command yet. Is it possible that your application is doing work? What exactly is your migration doing?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide, thanks for your response. open_tran_count value is different for each session as reported by sp_whoisactive. ranges from 0-2

Comment: @Andrew Sayer, thanks for your response. The host server cpu resource is under pressure with SQL using up to 97% as seen in Task Manager Processes.

Comment: @Andrew Sayer, avg_task_count is currently 21 while avg_runnable_tasks_count is 8

Comment: Generally speaking, as I do not know the details of your server. I would kill the one with `open_tran_count` =0. Figure out what is pending with the one count > 0.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide thank you very much for your time. In the end we had to restart all the application and db services. The issue is improved but not fully gone so we may have to add more cpu to the server. Thanks again.

Comment: You should use [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com/) to tell you of any active contention on your database server and add the results to your post. We may be able to further guide you with that information.

Comment: Thanks @J.D.. as I said, the matter has temporarily been closed but thanks for your time and comments all the same. Also, sp_WhoIsActive was one of the tools I used when I was investigating the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: @PTL_SQL No problem. Sorry I don't see any mention of your issue being closed on here, but np. In the future, if you want to share the results of `sp_WhoIsActive` there's a lot of helpful information in there.

Comment: @JD, thanks again. The issue is only temporarily closed. With respect to sharing results of sp_WhoIsActive, I don't think I'll be allowed to do that, as it will be giving info on our server to the public. I however do appreciate your readiness to help. Thanks again.